# AuthLogic - how to determine current user id throughout the system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, authlogic

I have set up AuthLogic almost exactly as per the AuthLogic example app at http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example.

After someone logs in as User, they can click on links that send them away into the system and away from the users controller. This is an incredibly noob question, but how can I access that User's ID and other attributes from anywhere else, such as an unrelated view or unrelated controller?

An example of what I'd like to do:

```
#matchings controller
@matching = Matching.find_by_user_id(user.id)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `current_user` or `@current_user`. The function that returns current_user is defined in application controller.

```
...
  private
  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

  def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
  end
...
```

So, you can use: 
`@matching = Matching.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)` or
`@matching = Matching.find_by_user(current_user)`